# Alternative to the contains selector

Tags: javascript, selector

I have a list of vehicle models and would like to display the associated types. As a selector I have written the types in a data-field. Now I want to hide with the class d-none all list items that do not match the selection.

This works with my current code. The problem is that I also get "Example Type 3" displayed in this example. But I only want to have "Example Type 2".

How can I make it so that only the 2nd element is displayed here but I can still search for "E-Tron S" or "E-Tron GT"?

My javascript so far:

```
    let searchText = "E-Tron";

containerItems = contentContainer.querySelectorAll('li[data-custom-field-filter-name^="Typ"]:not([data-custom-field-model*="' + searchText + '"])');

containerItems.forEach(function (el) {
    el.classList.add('d-none');
});
```

html list

```
<ul class="container">
<li class="has-button" data-custom-field-filter-name="Typ" data-custom-field-model=" Q5">
  <a href="#"><button> Example Type 1 </button></a>
</li>
<li class="has-button" data-custom-field-filter-name="Typ" data-custom-field-model=" E-Tron">
  <a href="#"><button> Example Type 2 </button></a>
</li>
<li class="has-button" data-custom-field-filter-name="Typ" data-custom-field-model="  E-Tron S| E-Tron GT">
  <a href="#"><button> Example Type 3 </button></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The code example doesn’t use contains?

Comment: @evolutionxbox OP is talking about `[data-custom-field-model*=`

Comment: Well you need to not do this with a selector  if you are expecting an exact match

Comment: Do the selection and then filter using JavaScript?

Comment: @epascarello how can i select without a selector?

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you give me a hint how to filter the selection?
i was thinking about to split the data-custom-field-model on '|' and than do a indexOf() query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact text matching or reg exp in the selector, so you need to do the filtering without using the contains selector.

```js
const searchText = "E-Tron";

const allLis = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-custom-field-filter-name="Typ"]');

var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + searchText + "($|\\|)");
allLis.forEach(x => {
  if(!regex.test(x.dataset.customFieldModel)) {
     x.classList.add("d-none");
  }
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
<li class="has-button" data-custom-field-filter-name="Typ" data-custom-field-model=" Q5">
  <a href="#"><button> Example Type 1 </button></a>
</li>
<li class="has-button" data-custom-field-filter-name="Typ" data-custom-field-model=" E-Tron">
  <a href="#"><button> Example Type 2 </button></a>
</li>
<li class="has-button" data-custom-field-filter-name="Typ" data-custom-field-model="  E-Tron S| E-Tron GT">
  <a href="#"><button> Example Type 3 </button></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you. thats the perfect solution for my use case